# Vitamio crashes on Android 6.0

Tags: android, vitamio

We are using Vitamio in our project as a MediaPlayer. When we change target SDK to API level 23 it crashes.
Logcat is as follows:

```
10-10 22:12:04.858: E/Vitamio[4.2.1]Player: LOAD FFMPEG ERROR: dlopen failed: /data/data/com.project/libs/libffmpeg.so: has text relocations
10-10 22:12:04.864: E/Vitamio[4.2.1]Player: FIND_NAME_SYM vvo, render_yuv
10-10 22:12:04.869: A/libc(9372): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 9372
```

There is an issue about this problem in Vitamio's github page : https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/312

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: If you are using ffmpeg for Android , you will not be able to use it for API level > 22 because support for text relocations are removed for API level > 22. So when FFMpeg fix this issue, you will be able to use it again. And if you are using Vitamio player for Android, there is the same issue. There is an interesting dialog in ffmpeg link below :)
Sources:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4928
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191235&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: We started using Exoplayer. And also there is a RTMP playing feature, too. Here is a blog post describing it. http://www.butterflytv.net/en/2016/01/25/play-rtmp-streams-and-seek-flv-files-with-exoplayer-for-developers/